# How to return array in variable instead of string javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var i = 1

var pattern1 = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "carrot"]

var pattern2 = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "carrot"]

var currentPat = "pattern" + i

alert(currentPat)
```

The currentPat variable is returning the string pattern1, its not returning the array. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try `pattern1[i]`. Note that broken code isn't a great substitute for a properly detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Why should it return something different? Your variable currentPat is simply a string. A string has nothing to do with the variable name itself.

Comment: @charlietfl the pattern is always changing so i need to be able to change the number in pattern1

Comment: `var currentPat = window["pattern" + i]` does what you want.

Comment: @connexo that doesnt work

Comment: That does work as long as  `pattern1` and `pattern2` are global variables (which both are in your sample code). Run the snippet in my answer below and you see it works.

Comment: Anytime you find yourself munging together numbers into variable names to access your data, you should probably be using an array. Concatenating text and numbers to address variables will get out of hand very quickly and Javascript gives you an abundance of better alternatives. See @mdatsev's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the patterns as 2 elements of an array and then you can use this:

```
var i = 1
var pattern = [];
pattern[1] = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "carrot"] 
pattern[2] = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "carrot"] 
var currentPat = pattern[i]
alert(currentPat)
```

If you can't change how the patterns are defined you could use `eval("pattern"+i)` but this isn't recommended since it makes the code harder to read and could lead to some security problems if used with user input.

Answer (score 2):

To use a variable property name, you need to access that via the square brackets syntax:

```js
var i = 1

var pattern1 = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "carrot"]

var pattern2 = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "carrot"]

var currentPat = window["pattern" + i]

console.log(currentPat)
```

Because both `pattern1` and `pattern2` are global variables in your example, they automatically become properties of the global object (which in a browser, is the `window` object).

```
window.pattern1
```

does exactly the same as

```
var prop = "pattern1"
window[prop]
```

or as

```
window["pattern1"]
```